# What are the PdfPCellEvent equivalent in iText7?

Tags: itext7

I am trying to run some samples from whitepaper "digitalsignatures20130304 A White Paper by Bruno Lowagie" [page 54]. I could not find the iText7 equivalents for PdfPCellEvent, PdfContentByte. 
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText 7 is a not a clone of iText 5 with some refactored package or class names, it has a new architecture. Thus, there is not always a 1:1 corresponding class but there are other ways to achieve the same effect.

It helps to look at the ports of the samples by the iText people; on github you can find many samples from the whitepaper ported to iText 7 in the [i7js-signatures](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures) project.

For example you mention page 54 of the [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](https://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) whitepaper. Considering the keywords you gave and the fact that there is but one example on that page, I assume you want to translate this method and helper class:

```java
protected PdfPCell createSignatureFieldCell(PdfWriter writer, String name) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setMinimumHeight(50);
    PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.createSignature(writer);
    field.setFieldName(name);
    field.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
    cell.setCellEvent(new MySignatureFieldEvent(field));
    return cell;
}

public class MySignatureFieldEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {
    public PdfFormField field;

    public MySignatureFieldEvent(PdfFormField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
        field.setPage();
        field.setWidget(position, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
    }
}
```

You find the port hereof in the class [C2_11_SignatureWorkflow](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02/C2_11_SignatureWorkflow.java):

```java
protected Cell createSignatureFieldCell(String name) {
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.setHeight(50);
    cell.setNextRenderer(new SignatureFieldCellRenderer(cell, name));
    return cell;
}

class SignatureFieldCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    public String name;

    public SignatureFieldCellRenderer(Cell modelElement, String name) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.draw(drawContext);
        PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.createSignature(drawContext.getDocument(), getOccupiedAreaBBox());
        field.setFieldName(name);
        field.getWidgets().get(0).setHighlightMode(PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
        field.getWidgets().get(0).setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(drawContext.getDocument(), true).addField(field);
    }
}
```

As you can see there are certain differences, in particular instead of an event a `Renderer` is used, and the field construction and positioning aren't separated anymore, they take place at the same location in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the ported code from your github link and that, worked. Thanks again.